# Debugging a JLink application in Creo 2.0

Tags: jlink

I am trying to use J-Link, the Java language toolkit for Pro-Engineer.
I get some knowledge from the API that provided by PTC.I need some tutorial or help file for model check.Please guide me to make better.

Any other suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the user guide in the ProE installation folder (\Common Files\jlinkug.pdf)?

Demo applications are in the "jlink_tutorial" and "jlink_appls" folder

```
Model model = curSession.GetCurrentModel();
ModelCheckInstructions checkInstr = pfcModelCheck.ModelCheckInstructions_Create();
checkInstr.SetMode(ModelCheckMode.MODELCHECK_NO_GRAPHICS);
checkInstr.SetShowInBrowser(true);
checkInstr.SetConfigDir(null);
checkInstr.SetOutputDir(null);
ModelCheckResults modelCheckResults = curSession.ExecuteModelCheck(model, checkInstr);
int numberOfErrors = modelCheckResults.GetNumberOfErrors();
int numberOfWarnings = modelCheckResults.GetNumberOfWarnings();
```

Comment: Yea i run some sample exercise that found in Creo. But I don't have any direction to start model check application.

Comment: I've added some code I found that seems to work for me. Not sure if it's usefull...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and response.Is there any source to know about Model check.I  google it but i can't get anything useful.

Comment: Not that I know of... 2 pages in the user guide (models - running modelCheck) but that's about all I found.

Comment: Yes of course ,But when we new to this concept we need to understand some basis things.But they never made that guide for that purpose.

Comment: Its not running .You mentioned "ModelCheckInstructions checkInstr" .But we didn't  Set any instructions.@ Tommy Bijnens

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you on that. Never worked on modelcheck myself... Btw, there is an example (pfcModelCheckExamples) in the jlink_appls folder. Not sure this will be helpful, but might be a good place to start from...

Comment: Thanks alot @ Tommy Bijnens